# Why "hexdump" displays a new empty line?

Tags: linux, hexdump

I have noticed a strange behavior when `hexdump` displays the hex values of a file, I have executed the following command:

```
hexdump -C 1.txt
```

And I got the following result:

[image]

Notice how `hexdump` displayed a new empty line (`0000000b`).

Why this empty line is displayed, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: For any non-empty input it always displays a final line containing the number of bytes in the file (in your case `0x0B` = 11 decimal). To get rid of it you can for example append `| head -n -1`.

Comment: Looks like an Answer, @AlexP !